# LinkedIn iOS in-app browser not playing inline video, breaks a-frame 360 VR video

Tags: ios, html5-video, linkedin-api, aframe

We have developed a VR experience using a-frame and 360 videos, that work perfectly well on all platforms, including iOS.

However, when linking from LinkedIn, the LinkedIn in-app browser opens, and the 360° videos open in the native iOS fullscreen player.

Is there a way to bypass the in-app browser in LinkedIn, and jump directly to Safari ?

Or even better, any way to make inline video play in LinkedIn's in-app browser on iOS ?

Comment: Struggling with the same issue. Any luck?

Comment: I found this demo which shows it is possible, but can't decipher how they're doing it: https://www.mist-t.co.jp/demo/showcase/inline.html

Opens inline in the LinkedIn iOS app for me, with a bit of janki-ness before play.

Comment: Nice lead, thanks. It looks like they are using video.js, but need to dig a bit more. My Japanese is non-existant, so its a bit difficult via their website.